# Where is the antecedent in this sentence?

Tags: reference

> No way of life has emerged of which the foundations were not laid communally.

In this sentence, what does the ***‘which’*** refer to?

Where is the antecedent?

Comment: No way of life I guess.

Answer (score -1):

The antecedent for which would be "way of life"